# How to save a list of strings in a variable?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what I tried:

```
>>> fa_data = []
>>> for i in mutate1.index:
...     with open('chr2_{}.fa'.format(i), 'r') as f:
...         fa = f.read()
...     fa = fa.replace('\n','')
...     seq3 = fa[-3:]
...     print(seq3)
... 
aac
gtt
cag
cta
tag
tca
gga
aaa
att
tac
taa
caa
agt
tta
```

Next, I want to keep every seq3 string as one list called fa_data, I expect fa_data be like [aac
gtt
cag
cta
tag
tca...]

```
fa_data = [fa_data + seq3[i] for i in seq3]
```

This line does not work.. Any suggestion on how to fix it or make the code more efficient is appreciated! Thx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try appending it to the list at the end of the code?

```
fa_data = []
>>> for i in mutate1.index:
...     with open('chr2_{}.fa'.format(i), 'r') as f:
...         fa = f.read()
...     fa = fa.replace('\n','')
...     seq3 = fa[-3:]
...     print(seq3)
...     fa_data.append(seq3)
```

Comment: Thats weird, we declared `fa_data` as a list at the beginning of the code.